# How to carry out arithmetic operations based on months over a combination of years?

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, datetime

Consisting of drought report/index for every month (there's multiple reports/indices per month), 2000–2021:

[image]

I want to show drought indices for all the months from a combination of 2000 through 2021, i.e., summing drought indices of Jan 2000, Jan 2001, Jan 2002, Jan 2003, Jan 2004, ... and Jan 2021, and returning it. And then summing drought indices for Feb 2000, Feb 2001, Feb 2002, Feb 2003, Feb 2004, ... and Feb 2021, and returning it. And then summing drought indices Mar 2000, Mar 2001, Mar 2002, Mar 2003, Mar 2004, ... and Mar 2021, and returning it. And then summing for Apr 2000, Apr 2001, Apr 2002, Apr 2003, Apr 2004, ... and Apr 2021, and returning it. And so on for the rest of the months.

I tried creating a regex str.contains() function to sum all the drought indices for all column values containing a certain month; however, that method only works for string, not datetime.

How do I go about carrying out this task?

Appreciate any assistance! (beginner at pandas and the whole jupyter environment)

Comment: Can you given a code example of what you have tried?

Comment: @sehan2

import re

print(df.loc[df['ValidEnd'].str.contains('^01*', flags=re.I, regex=True)]) #Show all the rows and columns with ValidEnd having '01' with other combination of numbers

Answer (score 0):

You could split the date first

```
iDate = str(20000104)
year = iDate[0:4]
month = iDate[4:6]
day = iDate[6:8]
year, month, day

('2000', '01', '04')
```

Then you might use the some of the various time and time looping functions of python. Some of them are used [here](https://alpynepyano.github.io/healthyNumerics/posts/python-loops-over-the-time.html) as an example